# How to make byte level tokenizer not split the <adjective> token?

Tags: python, huggingface-tokenizers

I have the text with custom tokens, like: `<adjective>` and I am trying to prepare a byte level tokenizer that won't split them:

```
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer = ByteLevel()
tokenizer.pre_tokenizer.pre_tokenize("<adjective>")

[('Ġ<', (0, 2)), ('adjective', (2, 11)), ('>', (11, 12)]
```

How to add `<adjective>` as not a special token, but a token that the tokenizer should not split?

Answer (score 0):

The new tokens to tokenizer in hugging-face transformer API can be added as follows:

`tokenizer.add_tokens('<adjective>')`

This would add '' as single token.

This would also require update to the model as:

`model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))`